# Read file using javascript (file path is Known)

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
  <script src =      "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<script type="text/javascript">

 document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

  // create a new instance of FileReader
  var reader = new FileReader();

  var file = this.files[0];

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){


  // By lines
  var lines = this.result.split('\n');
  for(var line = 0; line < 3; line++){
  document.write(lines[line]);
  document.write("<br>");
  }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
  };

  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

this is the code I used to read text file using given as a input. Without given as a input I want to read file which already know path.(eg: "index.html") .How could I want to change this code..

Comment: You can't, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: If we're talking about a file on your server, you can use `XMLHttpRequest`  with its `.responseType` property set to `'blob'`before passing it to your filereader.